# How to hide linux boot log over boot logo?

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, raspberry-pi4, meta-raspberrypi

I am compiling Yocto for Raspberry Pi 4, I am able to add a kernel boot logo by applying a patch on top of linux-raspberrypi kernel using [this](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/modify-the-linux-kernel-boot-logo-and-center-full-screen-display_1_16_10124740.html) blog post. With this blog I am able to boot with the boot logo but some of the logs coming over the logo.

(Previously I tried splash screen in Yocto, but it was showing the logo after a bit of time with those boot log in the screen)

Here is the final [booting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddmY2.jpg). Do you have any idea how to remove those logs over the kernel boot logo? (Completely hide those logs will make me happy)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`
add to end of line:
`fbcon=map:2`

Comment: While your answer might be correct, it would be better to explain what the addition will do.

Answer (score 0):

In Embedded Linux, You can add fbcon=map:2 to the boot parameters in the u-boot command line. (each u-boot environment has its parameters, which differ from one u-boot to another.)

Including this parameter will remove the boot log from the screen during the boot process.